# Match two sets (/lists) in Python

Tags: python, list, csv, set, match

I have two sets that are like below

Set A:

```
(['African American and Japanese', 'Indian', 'Chinese'])
```

Set B:

```
(['African', 'American', 'African American', 'Chinese', 'Russian'])
```

I want the output to be `(['African American', 'Chinese'])` but my script gives me either just Chinese or African, American, Chinese (splits African and American, I know that's how my script is, but am not sure how to edit).

I tried this so far.

```
import csv
alist, blist = [], []
with open("sample.csv", "rb") as fileA:
    reader = csv.reader(fileA, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        for row_str in row:
            alist.append(row_str)
            #alist = alist.strip().split() #If I use this, it also prints African, but doesn't print African American.
with open("ethnicity.csv", "rb") as fileB:
    reader = csv.reader(fileB, delimiter='\n')
    for row in reader:
        blist += row
        blist = [x.lower() for x in blist]
first_set = set(alist)
second_set = set(blist)
print [s for s in first_set if second_set in s]
```

EDIT:

Elements in SetA are not always separated by "and", it could be anything else or just a space.

Comment: *Why* should the output be produced, by what rules? Right now it looks like you could just return Set B and be done with it. Why look at Set A at all?

Comment: Can you narrow the problem down at all? Why not use the actual [`set` methods](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set)? You could reduce duplication by factoring out the code to extract the sets from the files, then test that separately from the logic for combining two sets. And shouldn't that be `[s for s in first_set if s in second_set]`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I tried condensing the sets and haven't observed that SetB and required output are the same. I edited the question now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I tried `[s for s in first_set if s in second_set]`, but that didn't help either.

Comment: `'African American'` isn't in Set A, so why should it be in the output? If you want to check if it's `in` [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) (hint!) element in the list, you will lose the benefits of the `set` (and then why isn't e.g. `'African'` included on its own?!) Unless you can clearly explain the logic, this will be very difficult to implement - as it stands, it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @jonrsharpe To be frank, I'm trying to compare multiple CSV files that are produced by someone else with my ethnicity.csv and get the ethnicity matches. So I made sets out of them and tried to compare. However, as you pointed, there's no `African American`, its clubbed with Japanese. But since there's no comma between African and American, I want my output to print African American instead of African,American. Hope it made sense.

Comment: Then you need more processing on the input - perhaps you should e.g. `str.split` on `'and'` if it's present in a given line? Once you have two `set`s that hold the **actual ethnicities you need** (e.g. `'Japanese'` and `'African American'` *separately*), this becomes a trivial `set` operation.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham since they are not African,American,Japanese in SetA, they are African American and Japanes (they are not separated).

Comment: @jonrsharpe The tricky part is, not all CSV files are in the same format. The only thing that's common is that those words are not separated by any delimiter as such.

Comment: I think you don't have much to be gained from using sets as you have a lot more processing to do, you need something like `[x for x in st2 if any(x == y.split(" and")[0] for y in st1)]` but there are lots more cases to catch I imagine so there is no way to fully answer your question

Comment: My point still stands; you need more input parsing to get to your sets. If a space is an acceptable delimiter, how could **anyone** tell whether `"African American"` is one or two ethnicities?! You need to decide what should count as a *"delimiter as such"* and process accordingly. This isn't currently an answerable question.

Comment: @dan, you have to find some way to normalise the data but I don't think that will be too easy without know all potential patterns

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I accept. But there're like hundreds of CSV files that are prepared by multiple people (so the format is not the same).

Comment: @dan, yep, therein lies the problem, it is going to be a fun task.

Answer (score 0):

You can rearrange list i.e. split the list item when it contains `"and"` as substring
Then use `intersection` method of set to get common items from both list.

code:

```
def convert(input):
    output = []
    for i in input:
        for j in i.split("and"):
            output.append(j.strip())
    return output

a = ['African American and Japanese', 'Indian', 'Chinese']
b = ['African American', 'Chinese']
a = convert(a)
print a
b = convert(b)
print set(a).intersection(set(b))
```

Output:

```
set(['African American', 'Chinese'])
```

Is this helpful ?

Comment: Thank you. "And" is not a separator always. I just edited my question indicating the same.

Comment: ok, we have to write code according to separators, need to analysis input data first before coding.

Answer (score 0):

If it could be *any* string (spaces included) separating the words, you can do something like this:

```
import re
sep = ' ; '
_a = sep.join(re.split(' [a-z]* ', sep.join(a)))
_b = sep.join(re.split(' [a-z]* ', sep.join(b)))
set(_b.split(sep)).intersection(_a.split(sep))
```

It won't work when `;` is separating two words in your lists... but I think it does handle all cases when you have a non-capatalized word separator.

Comment: I have just seen something similar in the comments, with the concern that there are many more cases to catch.  I think this covers all the potential cases.  It may not be the fastest way to do it, however, and is limited to working with lists of strings.

Comment: Thank you. So I tried doing `print [_a for _a in alist if ' ; '.join(blist).find(_a) != -1]` and it returned `[]`